# Changing the text in a textFieldButtonGrp by using the button

Tags: python, user-interface, maya

I'm trying to find a better way to change the `textfield` in multiple `textFieldButtongGrps` when I press their buttons.

Currently, what I have here works, but with this, I have to make additional lines in `select_Object()` for any additional `textFieldButtongGrps` I make in my UI. This is because I have to declare the name in `select_Object()`

Is there a way to change this so that if I make 6 `textFieldButtongGrps`, I can just have the `select_Object()` function use something similar to self?

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

window = cmds.window()
cmds.columnLayout()
tsL0 =cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(ed=False, adj=1,cal=(1,"left"),cw3=(10,100,25), cl3=("left","left","left") , 
                                buttonLabel='Root   FK',bc = 'select_Object()' )
gtF0 = tsL0 


tsL1 =cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(ed=False, adj=1,cal=(1,"left"),cw3=(10,100,25), cl3=("left","left","left") , 
                                buttonLabel='Root   FK',bc = 'select_Object()' )
gtF1 = tsL1
cmds.showWindow( window )



def select_Object():
    cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(**gtF0**, edit = True, tx ='' .join(sel),buttonLabel='IK OK',backgroundColor = (.5,.8,.2))
```

What I'd like to achieve:

```
def select_Object():
    cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(**self**, edit = True, tx ='' .join(sel),buttonLabel='IK OK',backgroundColor = (.5,.8,.2))
```

Comment: keep in mind you should not use string for ui commands. bc = select_Object  if there is no argument is enough, if you have arguments, use partial or lambda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you want your function to be more generic you can specify it to have one parameter where we will pass any `textFieldButtonGrp` to. And instead of defining the button's command as it is created, we can first create it, get a variable of the widget's final name, THEN define the function with that variable. That way you can create as many `textFieldButtonGrp` as you want and pass it to that function without doing additional code:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds


def select_Object(txt_btn_grp):  # Define parameter for the `textFieldButtonGrp`
    # Get selection.
    sel = cmds.ls(sl=True)
    if not sel:
        raise RuntimeError("No objects are selected!")

    cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(txt_btn_grp, edit=True, tx=''.join(sel), buttonLabel='IK OK', backgroundColor=(.5, .8, .2))


window = cmds.window()
cmds.columnLayout()

tsL0 = cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(
    ed=False, 
    adj=1, 
    cal=(1, "left"), 
    cw3=(10, 100, 25), 
    cl3=("left", "left", "left"), 
    buttonLabel='Root FK'
)
cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(tsL0, e=True, bc='select_Object(tsL0)')  # Now define the function with its variable.


tsL1 = cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(
    ed=False, 
    adj=1, 
    cal=(1, "left"), 
    cw3=(10, 100, 25), 
    cl3=("left", "left", "left"), 
    buttonLabel='Root FK'
)
cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(tsL1, e=True, bc='select_Object(tsL1)')

cmds.showWindow(window)
```

And just for fun, here's an example of creating a random amount of buttons to illustrate it even more:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds


def select_Object(txt_btn_grp):  # Define parameter for the `textFieldButtonGrp`
    print txt_btn_grp
    # Get selection.
    sel = cmds.ls(sl=True)
    if not sel:
        raise RuntimeError("No objects are selected!")

    cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(txt_btn_grp, edit=True, tx=''.join(sel), buttonLabel='IK OK', backgroundColor=(.5,.8,.2))


window = cmds.window()
cmds.columnLayout()

buttons = []

for i in range(10):
    buttons.append(cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(
        ed=False, 
        adj=1, 
        cal=(1, "left"), 
        cw3=(10, 100, 25), 
        cl3=("left", "left", "left"), 
        buttonLabel='Button {}'.format(i)
    ))
    cmds.textFieldButtonGrp(buttons[i], e=True, bc='select_Object(buttons[{}])'.format(i))

cmds.showWindow(window)
```

[image: Example]